# Using Wildcard Sql for searching a word in a TextField

Tags: sql, database, laravel, web, wildcard

To make it clearer I have this fields

```
 Columntobesearch
   aword1 bword1
   aword2 bword2
   aword3 bword4
```

Now what I want to do is search using the sql wild card so what I did is like this

```
 %searchbox%
```

I placed to wildcards on both ends of my search but what it searches is just the first word on the field

when I search 'aword' all of the fields is showing but when I search 'bword' nothing is showing, Please help.

Here is my Full Code

```
    $Input=Input::all();
    $makethis=Input::flash();
    $soptions=Input::get('soptions');
    $searchbox=Input::get('searchbox');
             $items = Gamefarm::where('roost_hen', '=',Input::get('sex'))
    ->where($soptions, 'LIKE','%' . $searchbox . '%')
    ->paginate(12);
```

Comment: Can you share the code, how you are making the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use mysql you can try this:

```
<?php
  $q = Input::get('searchbox');
  $results = DB::table('table')
        ->whereRaw("MATCH(columntobesearch) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
            array($q)
        )->get();
```

Ofcourse you need to prepare your table for full text search in your migration file with

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT search(columntobesearch)');
```

Any way, this is not the more scalable nor efficient way to do FTS.
For a scalable and reliable full text search I strongly recommend you see [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and implement any [Laravel package](https://github.com/shift31/laravel-elasticsearch) to this task

Comment: nice answer sir, but I just cant understand this part  "AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", whatdoes in boolean mode mean?

Comment: You can refer the docs of mysql for full text search in this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: I did this sir 
     $items = Gamefarm::where('roost_hen', '=',Input::get('sex'))
        ->whereRaw("MATCH(markings) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",array($searchbox))
       ->paginate(6);    but its still returning only the first phrase

Comment: I recommend you to read the mysql docs (posted in the past message) in the part of operators, and try for example a filter like this:        $q = str_replace(" ", " +", Input::get('searchbox'));